# Potentially frightening capacitor placement

Tags: capacitor, safety

[image: Schematic extract]

From the schematic of the Paton electrical modulated oscillator (Sydney, Australia, c.1952).

I am preparing to order new capacitors to replace the original paper and electrolytic ones. I noticed there is a 0.1uF paper capacitor on the primary side of the power transformer spanning from the active line to earth ground. I've not encountered this before (only across the lines and from neutral to earth ground.)

Seeking advice on its likely purpose and how to go about repair - I don't want to create any hazards but of course I do want the unit to work properly.

Comment: safety and best practice was sometimes different in the past. At that value it's clearly a filter, whether the main intention is protect the device from the environment or *vice versa* is not clear. You might do better to replace the whole mains input connector with a modern filtered one, unless of course historical accuracy is required. If you simply want to replace that cap, then use one that's properly rated. I think Y rated is needed rather than X in that position, but not sure.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two capacitors you need to worry about, one from neutral to earth, and one from live to earth. C39 and C40 (if I read properly). That is a common mains filter, as it is symmetric, so it works also in countries with unpolarized mains plugs so it does not matter which wire is live and which wire is neutral. It also means you must use earthed mains plug and socket.

So by itself, the filter caps are not an issue. But the original value and construction are an issue. First of all, those two capacitors need to be rated and classified Y capacitors for mains voltage safety. And 100nF is quite large, if not dangerously high value for a Y capacitor, it must be much lower to have high enough impedance to keep leakage currents at safe values.